# How would one add headers to requests in Her?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using [Her](http://her-rb.org/) to speak to an API I made so that I could retrieve information from it. I need an Authorization token passed in through the headers. How would I do this? The documentation doesn't show a solution anywhere, but it seems like a very much needed utility.

Comment: From looking at the documentation, it looks like you'll set up a middleware that will assign them, accepting 'env' and assigning a header to env[:request_headers]['Header-Name']

Answer (score 1):

@sethetter's comment basically covered it, but since I recently did something similar, I thought I would include some code, which someone might find useful in future. So, to do this, you would create a request middleware, which adds the desired headers in the `call` method. I had to do something similar, and the result looked like this:

```
class Authentication < Faraday::Middleware
  def call(env)
    env[:request_headers]['auth-token'] = generate_token(env)
    @app.call(env)
  end

  def generate_token(env)
    # generate the token based on the request, if needed
  end
end
```

And then, when you construct the API stack:

```
require 'authentication' #if you've defined it in a different file
@api = Her::API.new
@api.setup(:url => my_api_base_url) do |c|
    c.use Authentication
    # other middlewares as usual
end
```